# SQL query to return users with no active group memberships

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this schema, which has the ability to soft-delete/archive a group:

```
create table users (id int, name varchar(255));
create table groups (id int, name varchar(255), archived_at datetime);
create table memberships (group_id int, user_id int);

insert into users (id, name) values 
  (1, 'no groups'),
  (2, 'only active groups'),
  (3, 'only archived groups'),
  (4, 'active and archived groups');

insert into groups (id, name, archived_at) values
  (1, 'active group', null),
  (2, 'archived group', '2021-04-13');

insert into memberships (user_id, group_id) values
  (2, 1),
  (3, 2),
  (4, 1),
  (4, 2);
```

And I want to query users that have "no groups": exactly zero Active (non-archived) groups, plus zero or more Archived groups.

```
-- How do I get this to return only users 1 and 3?
select *
from users u
left join memberships m on m.user_id = u.id
left join groups g on g.id = m.group_id
where
  m.group_id is null
  or 
  g.archived_at is not null
```

Is this possible with the current schema?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1szvQmQHp1g84Ex9WvRHy/1

Comment: The SQL query you have makes sense to me returning 3 rows .. Can you display your intended result?

Comment: Intended result is only users 1 and 3

Comment: OK .. Then what differentiates User 3 and User 4?  And how can we express that in the SQL statement?  --  Reason I ask, is that with the current data set there's no way to separate them other than hard coding  `user.name` or user.id`

Comment: As stated in the post, User 3 has 'only archived groups' and User 4 has 'active and archived groups'

Comment: Read my edited comment ..  There's nothing differentiating them other than `user.id` or `user.name` So you can't expect to separate them with the current schema / query.

Comment: The memberships table defines that relationship

Comment: Yes .. But if users `3` and `4` BOTH have an **association** of `2` In the `members` table -- There is nothing separating them!  I fear you are missing the logic here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231087/discussion-between-jemminger-and-zak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from memberships m join
                       groups g
                       on m.group_id = g.id
                  where m.user_id = u.id and g.archived_at is null
                 );
```

Presumably, an active group is one that has not been archived.

Comment: Yeah, that might be it!  I'll test it more tomorrow